# Output disc space of folders as JSON

Tags: json, tree

I want to output the size of folders to a json file with the following command

`tree -d -JL 3 --charset utf-8 --du $HOME/share >> discspace.json`

But the command won't output valid json. Instead it outputs following:

```
[
  {"type":"link","name":"/home/user/share","contents":[
    {"type":"directory","name":"folder1","size":16384,"contents":[
      {"type":"directory","name":"folder1_1","size":4096,"contents":[]},
      {"type":"directory","name":"folder1_2","size":4096,"contents":[]},
      {"type":"directory","name":"folder1_3","size":4096,"contents":[]}>>,<<
    ]},
    {"type":"directory","name":"folder2","size":20480,"contents":[
      {"type":"directory","name":"folder2_1","size":4096,"contents":[]},
      {"type":"directory","name":"folder2_2","size":8192,"contents":[
        {"type":"directory","name":"folder2_2_1","size":4096,"contents":[]}>>,<<
      ]},
      {"type":"directory","name":"folder2_3","size":4096,"contents":[]}>>,<<
    ]}>>,<<
  ]},
  {"type":"report","size":36881,"directories":9}
]
```

When validating the json I'm gettings errors because too many commas are used (the ones I marked with `>>,<<`).

which command would be better/correct?

Comment: I think the simplest way may be just cleaning up `tree` output. You can also run `du` and convert it's output to json with any text processing utility. But this problem with `tree` is really something you should consider reporting as a bug to the developers so it can be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with using any text processing utility. I just reported the tree bug though.

Comment: @Kalim is there a public reference/tracking to that bug report? Are you willing to share that here?